# Check a value for 5 different years by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Today I'm a bit stuck with a problem that I'm not being able to somewhat efficiently resolve. I have a DataFrame like this:

```
id    Date        Days    Value
1     20130101     95      100
1     20130102     100     100
.
1     20140101     120     90
.
1     20150101     150     90
.
1     20180101     190     85
2     20130101      98     80
.
2     20140101      70     80
.
2     20180101      150    80
```

So, it's monthly data, and I want to create a column named `Value_t5` that takes the `Value` of a given row, five years into the future if in each 12-month gap, `Value` was over 90 days. So, for the first row, I have to check `20140101`, `20150101`, `20160101`, `20170101` and `20180101`. Because `Days` is over 90 in all of those rows, `Value_t5` will take the value `85` for the `20130101` row (`nan` for the rest, because I didn't add more data). Then, for `id` number 2, the `20130101` would take a `nan` value, because on `20140101`, `Days` was below 70. So, the expected output would be:

```
 id    Date        Days    Value   Value_t5
1     20130101     95      100      85
1     20130102     100     100     np.nan
.
1     20140101     120     90      np.nan
.
1     20150101     150     90      np.nan
.
1     20180101     190     85      np.nan
2     20130101      98     80      np.nan
.
2     20140101      70     80      np.nan
.
2     20180101      150    80      np.nan
```

I'm guessing some kind of combination of `groupby` , `.all()` and `pd.DateOffset()`, might be involved in the answer, but I'm not being able to find it without haveing to merge 5 offsetted dataframes.

Also I've got 17 million rows of data, so `apply` is probably not the best idea.

My best bet would be to create a `n x 5` matrix with all yearly `Days` values for each row and then processing that. Is there any straightforward way to do this ?

Comment: Try dask with 17m row.

Comment: But `apply` + `groupby` is even slower in dask than pandas

Answer (score 0):

If your data is monthly, you can simply do rolling:

```
# toy data:
reps = 100000
dates = np.tile(pd.date_range('2005-01-01', '2020-12-01', freq='MS'),reps)
ids = np.repeat(np.arange(reps), len(dates)//reps)

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids,
                   'Date': dates,
                   'Days': np.random.randint(0,20, len(dates)),
                   'Values': np.arange(len(dates))})

# threshold, put 90 here
thresh = 5

# rolling months
roll = 5

df['valid'] = df['Days'].ge(thresh).astype(int)
groups = df.groupby('id')
df['5m'] = groups['valid'].rolling(roll).sum().values
df['5m'] = groups['5m'].shift(-roll).values
df['value_t5'] = np.where(df['5m']==roll, groups['Values'].shift(-roll*12), np.nan)
```

**Output** (head):

```
   id       Date  Days  Values  valid   5m  value_t5
0   1 2013-01-01     5       0      1  5.0      60.0
1   1 2013-02-01    11       1      1  5.0      61.0
2   1 2013-03-01    12       2      1  5.0      62.0
3   1 2013-04-01     8       3      1  4.0       NaN
4   1 2013-05-01     9       4      1  4.0       NaN
```

**Performance**: On my computer, that took about 40 seconds (for 19MM rows).

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang, I'll try to adapt your answer. The difference is I'm  rolling just on 5 one year intervals but on monthly data, so I'll have to change some things, but it seems your answer will help me a lot!

Comment: I'm having troubles adapting this line: `df['5m'] = groups['valid'].rolling(roll).sum().values` to get the sum on one year gaps, do you have any ideas?